# Recovering variables from try/catch in Powershell

Tags: powershell

I am having trouble with a restart script.  I am trying to sent out a Restart-Computer command to a series of servers and capture failures so that I can retry them in another manner (in this case through the VIC).

Here is my code snippet

```
try {
    Restart-Computer -ComputerName $_.Servername -Credential $cred -Force -ErrorAction Stop
    }
catch [system.exception] {
    #Create output object
    $output = [pscustomobject] @{
        Servername = $_.Servername
        Domain = $_.Domain
        Environment = $_.Environment
        VIC = $_.VIC
        }
    Export-Csv -InputObject $output -Path C:\temp\VICredo.csv -Force -NoTypeInformation
    }
}
```

The issue here is that the $_ variables don't make it down to the catch block, so I have no way of writing them to a "retry list".  Can anyone think of a way to do this that works?

Answer (score 1):

When it encounters the terminating error, the original pipeline is stopped.  Another pipeline is started, and what's in that pipeline is the error.

You can get around that by switching to using a foreach loop.

Comment: This is currently in a foreach loop, I just left a lot of that out because it was more info than was necessary.  Do you mean a foreach loop within the try/catch?

Comment: No, foreach(){}  as opposed to foreach-object{}.

Answer (score 0):

You can always assign `$_` to a dedicated variable and use that one throughout the `try`/`catch` block:

```
... | ForEach-Object {
  try {
    $comp = $_
    Restart-Computer -ComputerName $comp.Servername ...
  } catch [System.Exception] {
    #Create output object
    $output = [PsCustomObject] @{
      Servername  = $comp.Servername
      Domain      = $comp.Domain
      Environment = $comp.Environment
      VIC         = $comp.VIC
    }
    Export-Csv ...
  }
} | ...
```

Or, as [@mjolinor](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24291631/1630171) suggested, you could use a `foreach` loop:

```
foreach ($comp in ...) {
  try {
    Restart-Computer -ComputerName $comp.Servername ...
  } catch [System.Exception] {
    #Create output object
    $output = [PsCustomObject] @{
      Servername  = $comp.Servername
      Domain      = $comp.Domain
      Environment = $comp.Environment
      VIC         = $comp.VIC
    }
    Export-Csv ...
  }
}
```

The disadvantage of the `foreach` loop is that you cannot pass its output into a pipeline without putting the loop in a sub-expression or assigning its output to a variable first.

Comment: You can make a foreach loop work with the pipeline with a sub-expression - $(foreach ($i in $a){}) |.  No intermediate variables required.

Comment: @mjolinor Ah, yes. I forgot about that. Added.

Comment: OK.  Thanks so much both.  I never really understood what the difference was with foreach and ForEach-Object.  This helps.